Labeling Data - Stereo Vision - KITTI Dataset
I am trying to understand going from image labeling 2D to 3D stereo vision.
When you label 2D images each image has bounding boxes that you can output as a txt file which gives the location and size of the object, what I don't understand is when you have a pair of left and right images, do you label both images, or the disparity map, or none of the above?
For example the KITTI dataset contains a txt file with all the bounding box information, but only one txt file is given, which image would they have labelled the left or right?
Ultimately I want to be doing 3D object detection and not 2D but I am stuck trying to understand how to go about labeling a pair..
Thank you if you can provide any help in understanding.
I have tried labelling in 2D but don't understand how to then label a stereo pair of images left and right compared to traditional labelling of one image in 2D
